# Typescript second parameter (`params`) type based on first parameter

Tags: typescript

How to force a proper second argument type for the `createMessage` method here:

```
const EMAIL_TEMPLATES = {
  DOCTOR_SIGNUP: DoctorSignupOutput,
  CHANGE_PASSWORD: PasswordParams
} as const;

@Injectable()
export class EmailService {

  sendEmail() {
    console.log('Email sent!');
  }

  createMessage(template: keyof typeof EMAIL_TEMPLATES, params: ?) {

  }


}
```

so i.e. only objects of type `DoctorSignupOutput` are allowed, when template equals `DOCTOR_SIGNUP`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

try like that

```js
  createMessage<
    T extends keyof typeof EMAIL_TEMPLATES, // <- T points to a key
    R extends (typeof EMAIL_TEMPLATES)[T] // <- R points to the type of that key
  >(template: T, params: R) {

  }
```

---

A detailed example:

```js
interface MyInterface { 
    keyString: string;
    keyNumber: number;
}

function createMessage<
  O extends object, // object itself
  K extends keyof O, // all its keys
  V extends O[K] // types of keys, once K is specified, it's narrowed to related type.
>(object: O, key: K, value: V) {
    console.log(object, key, value);
}

const data: MyInterface = {
    keyString: 'hello',
    keyNumber: 777,
};

createMessage(data, 'keyString', 'world'); // works
createMessage(data, 'keyNumber', 42); // works

createMessage(data, 'keyString', 42); // fails due to wrong type
createMessage(data, 'keyNumber', 'world'); // fails due to wrong type
createMessage(data, 'keyUnknown', 'random'); // fails due to missed key in the original interface.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-kQ2HMZGdtrY4x410k8KIEaxab0z70ABVEAUEAbEC5qBwVyaESF4NwUPh8u7EQjGIuR6RHRgBkeBiMUCFBcEvDg4hAA)